# Copy and Pasting Script for the Alphabet and Numbers

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

How would I create the following shortcut?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> = Copy selected text to a unique "A" variable.

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> = Paste the text which is binded to the unique "A" variable.

And then extend this to the keys A-Z and 0-9?

For example, suppose I select the text "aaa" and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.  I then select the text "bbb" and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.  Then, if I were to press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> followed by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, I should see the text string "bbbaaa".

Is there a way to do this in linux?

Comment: In what application?

Comment: I suspect a more searchable title for the question would be something like "How to create additional keyboard copy buffers?"

Comment: X11 has several clipboard buffers - you should look into those, maybe?